# Stripping empty cells from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Im trying to strip the empty cells from an unstructured excel file that I imported into pandas. I successfully removed the nan cells using this lamda I found `df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))` it works but it automatically moves the cells that do have data. This is an issue as the data I'm working with is a list of questions and answers so they need to stay together.

Im looking for a way to re index the data after it has been stripped, i think this may be possible by merging the data with a copy of itself using pd.merge but was unable to figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly and you won't need the questions with empty answers you can just drop the entire row and then reset the index.

```
df2 = df2.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```